# How can I fix flexible stucco?

Tags: repair, walls, stucco, patch

Around the outside of the house, the concrete base is covered with a layer of styrofoam and a layer of this flexible stucco material. I'm not really sure what exactly is. This sheet looks like *stucco* with a plastic mesh through it (see images).

I'm trying to fix the damaged parts and I would like to use the same materials or something similar which would be very close to what it already is.

Front of the *stucco* layer:
[image: Front of the *stucco* layer]

Back of the *stucco* layer:
[image: Back of the *stucco* layer]

Undamaged wall:
[image: Undamaged Wall]

Damaged wall:
[image: Damaged wall]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is  a system called EIFS for short. Here is a link to get to the care and repair of this type of finish.

Sto Exterior Insulation and Finish Systems (EIFS) Manuals: [StoTherm EIFS Repair and Maintenance Guide](http://www.stocorp.com/index.php/en/Download-document/2502-EIFS-Repair-and-Maintenancce-Guide-S707.html)

Comment: Link only answers are only helpful as long as the link is good. Please consider summarizing the information found in the link here.

Comment: It has the answer in there,  I figured to have the whole maintenance and repair manual might be handy. On top of that I have never tried to get a PDF on Stack. I will try to abbreviate it